# SELECT from MySQL table - Move down every rows of single column by 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have MySQL table. I use this to display data on my website:

```
$daily = "SELECT id, weight, sys FROM scale ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 24";
$result_daily = $conn->query($daily);

<table>
while($row = $result_daily->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo "<tr><<td>". $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["weight"] . "</td><td>". $row["sys"]. "</td></tr>";
}echo "</table>";}?>
```

This will show data like this:

```
  id. weight  sys
| 5. | 32.5 | 15 |
| 4. | 31.5 | 14 |
| 3. | 34.5 | 17 |
| 2. | 31.5 | 15 |
| 1. | 30.0 | 16 |
```

I would like to move down every rows of sys column by 1 row. Like this:

```
  id. weight  sys
| 5. | 32.5 |    |
| 4. | 31.5 | 15 |
| 3. | 34.5 | 14 |
| 2. | 31.5 | 17 |
| 1. | 30.0 | 15 |
```

Comment: Why is that data, in effect, being pulled from a completely different row?

Comment: Sys is system run time wich is measure from wake up until sleep. So this data will uploaded to szerver only on next wake up

Comment: Weird, but easier to accommodate on the application layer by displaying the last element as offset from the others, e.g. `$rows[$i-1][2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$daily = "SELECT id, weight, sys FROM scale ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 24";
$result_daily = $conn->query($daily);
$s="";

<table>
while($row = $result_daily->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo "<tr><<td>". $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["weight"] . "</td><td>". $s. "</td></tr>";
 $s = $row["sys"];
}echo "</table>";}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the previous `sys` value in a local variable while looping:

```php
$prev_sys = '';
while($row = $result_daily->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo "<tr><<td>". $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["weight"] . "</td><td>". $prev_sys. "</td></tr>";
 $prev_sys= $row["sys"];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to fetch all the data into an array and then use a numerical key to access the previous row. If there is no previous row then provide empty string as a default value.

```
$daily = "SELECT id, weight, sys FROM scale ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 24";
$result_daily = $conn->query($daily)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo "<table>";
foreach ($result_daily as $key => $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["weight"] . "</td><td>". ($result_daily[$key++]["sys"] ?? ''). "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```